# How to concatenate multiple files with same header? Some of the files only have header

Tags: linux, bash, concatenation

I have a huge number of files named 0.file.csv,.., 1000.file.csv. I need to concatenate the files, only keep the header of the first file, and get rid of the headers of the rest of the files. The solution I came up with is:

```
sudo awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' {0..1000}.file.csv > file.csv
```

But, this solution does not work if some of the files only have header.

The sample input is:

```
0.file.csv
person_id, dob, year, subject, degree
0,1984/12/01,2014,math,ms

1.file.csv
person_id, dob, year, subject, degree

2.file.csv
person_id, dob, year, subject, degree
200,1990/03/12,2015,physics,bs
201,1991/04/18,2015,math,ms
```

The output should be:

```
person_id, dob, year, subject, degree
0,1984/12/01,2014,math,ms
200,1990/03/12,2015,physics,bs
201,1991/04/18,2015,math,ms
```

Comment: You need some pattern that `awk` can use to distinguish between a header line and a non-header line. Note that if said pattern cannot match a true data line, the `FNR` and `NR` tests are no longer necessary.

Comment: I get precisely the output you expect from the precise command you use. What output did you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR>1 || NR==1' {0..1000}.file.csv
```

But this does exactly the same thing as your original (but without the reliance on `next`). It produces the expected output, but I don't see why your original doesn't. (It did when I tried it.)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU grep:

```
cat 0.file.csv > file.csv
grep -vh '^person_id, dob, year, subject, degree$' {1..1000}.file.csv >> file.csv
```

Output to file.csv:

```
person_id, dob, year, subject, degree
0,1984/12/01,2014,math,ms
200,1990/03/12,2015,physics,bs
201,1991/04/18,2015,math,ms
```

or with GNU sed and same output:

```
cat 0.file.csv > file.csv
sed -sn '2,$p' {1..1000}.file.csv >> file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate strategy using head and tail:

```
head -1 0.file.csv > file.csv
tail -qn +2 {0..1000}.file.csv >> file.csv
```

Contents of file.csv:

> person_id, dob, year, subject, degree
>   0,1984/12/01,2014,math,ms
>   200,1990/03/12,2015,physics,bs
>   201,1991/04/18,2015,math,ms